# Extract query returning Decimal('value'), float is expected

Tags: python, postgresql, proxy, decimal, psycopg2

I saw a topic with the same question on Stackoverflow but I have a bit different question. My system locally return the value as float, but on GitHub Actions its Decimal. What could be the reason

```
session = app.ReadOnlySession()
query_ = text(query)
result_proxy = session.execute(query_, fetched_options)
res = result_proxy.fetchone()[0]
session.close()
if input_key in ["local_hour", "day_of_week"]:
    logger.info(f"ITS FOR TEST: {res=}")
```

Query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(dow FROM now())
SELECT EXTRACT(hour FROM now())
```

GitHub:

```
ITS FOR TEST: res=Decimal('1')
ITS FOR TEST: res=Decimal('13')
```

Locally:

```
ITS FOR TEST: res=1.0 
ITS FOR TEST: res=13.0
```

I want to have float return on GitHub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a difference in PostgreSQL versions.  Starting from PostgreSQL version 14, PostgreSQL returns values of type `numeric` for `EXTRACT` queries; previously it returned `float8` (or `double precision`).

From the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14.html#id-1.11.6.11.4):

> Change EXTRACT() to return type numeric instead of float8 (Peter Eisentraut)
>
> This avoids loss-of-precision issues in some usages. The old behavior can still be obtained by using the old underlying function date_part().

Psycopg2 [represents](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types) `float8` as a Python `float` but represents `numeric` as `Decimal`.  As the release notes state, you can use `date_part` instead of `extract` if you want a float type returned.

Comment: Thank you very much, solved by down grade postgresql to version 11